# Graficar funciones en python usando matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Soy nuevo tanto en python como en matplotlib y quisiera saber como graficar una ecuacion, por ejemplo
20x + 30y = 30. ¿Alguna idea de como lo podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matplotlib necesitas pasarle una lista de coordenadas X y otra lista con las correspondientes coordenadas Y.

Una forma simple puede ser la de generar varios valores de X en un bucle, para cada uno evaluar tu función, e ir almacenando en listas separadas las X y las Y que vas generando. Así:

```
def funcion(x):
   # Despejamos la y en la ecuación 20x+30y=30
   return (30-20*x)/30

X = []
Y = []
for x in range(20):
   y = funcion(x)
   X.append(x)
   Y.append(y)
```

Una vez tienes ambas listas usarías así matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Para obtener la siguiente figura:

[image: Figura]

Otra posibilidad más frecuentemente usada es hacer uso de la biblioteca numpy, que puede operar vectorialmente con listas de números. En este caso X sería un vector con varios valores para las abcisas, y cuando pasas ese vector a la función antes escrita, lo que te retorna es otro vector con los correspondientes valores de las ordenadas. Te evitas así el bucle, al tener una sola llamada a la función que calcula "de una vez" todos los valores necesarios gracias a la magia vectorial de numpy:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(20)
Y = funcion(X)
```

La forma de generar el plot sería la misma de antes, pues matplotlib admite indistintamente listas python o vectores numpy.